# How to loop in each dictionary key and value and print in UILabel

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, foreach, uilabel

I've created a dictionary value and `UILabel`, I want to loop in each dictionary value and key and print out each value and key in it own `UILabel` and `UITextView`.

Here is my code --->>

```
var cabinets = ["Kitchen": "An effective way to make a modern statement in your kitchen is to make a drastic change to your existing cabinets. Even if you’re on a tight budget, by hiring a trusted kitchen cabinet remodeling company, you could appreciate the outcome you’re provided with for years to come.", "Living Room": "Blah Blah. is locally owned and operated in Portland, OR, and our courteous contractors are dedicated to offering customized support. We're available to assist you Monday - Friday, 9am - 6pm, and Saturday - Sunday, by appointment.", "Bathroom": "At Blah Blah., we understand the importance of having enough room to house the items you use on a regular basis. That's why we offer a wide selection of bathroom cabinets in all shapes and sizes.", "Closets": "We’ve got the muscle, the tools, and the coordination to seamlessly install beautiful new custom closets in your home or place of business."]

for key in cabinets.keys{

    if let value = cabinets[key] {
        UILabel = value
        titleLabel.text = key
    }

}
```

Comment: If you loop on your values and keep updating the same label, this label will only have the last value at the end of the loop... You'd better use a table view for listing text like this.

Comment: Also, the line `UILabel = value` won't work because UILable is not of type String.